# How to loop through a JSON array with useEffect in React?

Tags: json, reactjs, use-effect

I am trying to loop through a JSON array with useEffect. When I use the below code (with the array removed from useState) with a single user specified, I am able to get the data. However it does not work with the entire array...any suggestions would be appreciated.

```
function GitHubUser() {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(`https://api.github.com/users/`)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(setData)
      .catch(console.error);
  }, []);

  if (data) {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>{data.userId}</h1>
        <img src={data.avatar_url} width={100} alt={"github avatar"}/>
        <p>{data.login}</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
  return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doen't work because when you do `if (data)` it returns true because empty array is `true`

```js
const data = [];
if (data) {
  console.log("Empty array is true");
} else {
  console.log("Empty array is false");
}
```

So... when you try to get `userId` from an empty array it throws an error.

If data is supposed to be an array...

```js
function GitHubUser() {
    const [data, setData] = useState([]);
    useEffect(() => {
        fetch("https://api.github.com/users")
            .then((res) => res.json())
            .then(setData)
            .catch(console.error);
    }, []);

    if (data) {
        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                {data.map((user) => (
                    <div>
                        <h1>{user.userId}</h1>
                        <img src={user.avatar_url} width={100} alt={"github avatar"} />
                        <p>{user.login}</p>
                    </div>
                ))}
            </React.Fragment>
        );
    }
    return null;
}
```

You have to map each user to the expected output component. Using a map will prevent the previous behaviour because if no elements are present in the array, it will not map anything and return an empty component instead of an error.

If data is not supposed to be an array, then you shouldn't use a map nor initialize the state with an empty array because before running the `fetch` it will try to render the component and fail.

Answer (score 0):

Is this something like you u want?

- I removed the backslash after `https://api.github.com/users*here*`.
- I set the data in useEffect hooks, in your example you didnt do it.
- And mapped the array in data, it shows all the github users with
  images and names.

.

```
function GitHubUser() {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(`https://api.github.com/users`) // removed the backslash here
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(data => setData(data)) // changed this line
      .catch(console.error);
  }, []);

  console.log(data)


    return (
      <div>
        {data.map((item, key) => <> // Mapping through the array here
        <h1 key={key}>{item.id}</h1>
        <img src={item.avatar_url} width={100} alt={"github avatar"}/>
        <p>{item.login}</p>
        </>
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Comment: The second point has the same behaviour as the one posted by the OP. You are passing a function to be executed, the one from the OP will take the data returned from the `then`  "implicitly" while the one posted here is explicit. The final result should be the same

Comment: It works in sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hooks-counter-demo-forked-qyx88

Comment: It does https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hooks-counter-demo-forked-jni3o

Comment: @luckongas whatever man, problem is solved :)

Comment: Sure! I thought that you were asking what I said, not showing your example, sorry. Both solutions work ;)